# How to handle OutOfMemory Windows phone

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, memory, listbox, windows-phone-7.1

I have a `listbox` in which I `load images dynamically from the web as user scrolls`. Consider it an infinite scroll. My current `display size is 72X72`. But if I `increase the display size to 288x288 (4 times)` after few minutes of scrolling the app exits giving a `outofmemory system error`. It has started to occur very often on my `512MB device` for large images. This concerns me because it will occur more quickly for `256 MB` devices. How to handle such situation as try catch do not handle these system errors? What is the `most optimum` way of handling such a huge list of images?

Comment: Do you resize the incoming images from the web before storing them locally? To fill up 512MB with 72x72 images, you will need a whole lot of images.

Comment: ya i have a huge source of images. And i dont resize them while storing locally.

Comment: I think you should then, there is no point in storing a 800x600 image if you only want to display it in 72x72.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also gone through this damm issue of WP7 or WP7.5.

**There is a huge issue with Images in Windows phone 7.**

A image of appox size 900kb when read from Isolated storage as stream and set as a source of Bitmap class object than u will see there is huge change/rise in memory usage (in my case 5-6MB).

**Just go through this website and u will understand the rest.**
[Silverlight-s-big-image-problem-and-what-you-can-do-about-it](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/12/17/silverlight-s-big-image-problem-and-what-you-can-do-about-it.aspx)

**For long image listing issue**

1. Scale down the images u get from the server.
2. Use [LongListSelector tool](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/LongListSelector-walkthrough) to list images using data virtualization technique

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jeff Wilcox [MemoryDiagnosticHelper](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/10/30/that-memory-thing-i-promised-you.aspx?Redirected=true) to control the memory usage. If it's about 90 mb, you can run image clean up process.
Just unload BitMaps (`Image.Source = null`) for images wich user can't see at the moment.

And also it's good practice to compress images (use the server side compression for example).